# Simple Q Iterator <Object E> of Abstract Class

Tags: java, interface, casting, iterator, abstract-class

Hi guys can u tell until tomorrow ??

Well,
I dont use java.util.iterator to create my iterator interface, just create my own so

I have 2 Iterators: AccountIterator / FileIterator, and my objective its to iterate abstract object "Account" and object "File" to my Main class in "deafult" package

(Also have 2 extends to AbstractAccount.class (BasicClass.class / PremiumClass.class, and AbstractAccount.class implements Account.interface)

There is my Iterator Interface:

```
package cs;

public interface Iterator<E> {
    public void init() ;
    public boolean hasNext();
    public E next();
}
```

There is my Account Iterator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0avp.png

I cant use cast, any ideas 
Cumps and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply modify the class header to specify the object type.

Use

```
public class AccountIterator implements Iterator<Account>
```

rather than general

```
public class AccountIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>
```

You will have to change E to Account.

Comment: thanks for fast help (:

one more question ? in my interface Account (extends to 2 diferent class) i have:

"Iterator<E> itFiles();" to return to Main.class
if iterator its to return FileIterator i change E to File (File.interface)
if iterator its to return AccountIterator i change E to Account (Account.interface)

Answer (score 1):

You've parametrized your class with type `E`, but your account array is of type `Account`. `accounts[index]` returns an `Account` and not `E`.

You probably meant to implement an `Iterator<Account>`. Change the class signature to this...

```
public class AccountIterator<E> implements Iterator<Account>
```

The Impl will then take care of your generic preference and it will work out.

```
class MyIter implements Iterator<String>
{
    String [] arr = new String[10];

    public void init()
    {
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public String next()
    {
        return arr[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for fast help (:

one more question ? in my interface Account (extends to 2 diferent class) i have:

"Iterator<E> itFiles();" to return to Main.class
if iterator its to return FileIterator i change E to File (File.interface)
if iterator its to return AccountIterator i change E to Account (Account.interface)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to return a `File` or `Account` based on the Iterator type. Yes you can use `<File>` and `<Account>` where you want to return the corresponding type.

Comment: thanks a lot \o/ its all class working now, less in main (Nothing happens when list all users)

private static void listAll(Server srv, Scanner in) {
Iterator<Account> itAccounts = srv.itAccounts();
itAccounts.init();
while(itAccounts.hasNext()){
   Account a = itAccounts.next();
   a.getEmail();
  }
  System.out.println("DF");
 }<code>